# How to prevent users to login to my site more than one sessions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, session

I am developing an ASP.net site (using .NET 4, EF, jQuery Ajax, SQL Server 2008 R2). In this site I want to prevent `multi-login`. I mean if you log in to site, you can not log in to site again from other browser or computer since you are logged in already.

I plant an idea and developed it on my site, but it have a problem and it is because that problem that I decide to ask a question here

I have a SQL Server table like this :

```
Id        [int]            NOT NULL   IDENTITY(1,1)   //PK
UserId    [int]            NOT NULL                   //Relation to User table
Key       [nvarchar](50)   NOT NULL                   //Unique
```

When a user logs into the site, I insert a row into this table like this :

```
UserId = The Id of logged in user 
Key = Session.SessionId
```

and also there is a code for delete a record from this table that execute when:

1. User try to log out from its account
2. on `Session_End` event in `global.asax`

Everything works correct and perfect, just :

Problem: when the user closes the browser, that row does not get deleted (I thought when he close the browser, its row in that table will delete on `Session_End` event , but it did not!!!)

What can I do? Any solution for this problem? Should I change my strategy or there is a solution?

Sorry about my bad syntax. I am new in english

Any idea can be useful

regards

Foroughi

**UPDATE1** : i do not use ASP **membership** and manage my users myself

**UPDATE2** : i use **InProc** mode for my session state with 20 minutes timeout

Comment: Isn't it easier to log out the existing session when the user does a new login? This is also more practical when the user forgot to logout at a different location (e.g. home/work).

Comment: @marc_s thanks dude and sorry about them

Comment: @AliForoughi: no problem - the question is still clear and perfectly understandable

Comment: @TheNail , yes you are right , but in this case (i mean my site) it is better to do something like my idea, anywaym thank you :)

Comment: @TheNail , in other hand , this is a decision of my project manager, and i have to to that :(

Comment: What does your project manager know about it? Or you can go for @Myles McDonnell's answer, and still provide the option to log out the existing session, as this will likely improve the solution.

Comment: @TheNail , yes he know :(. you are right , i am working on these idea, and because i am new in English , it takes some minutes to find out what they want to say me in their replies. sorry , i accept the better answer as soon as i can possible :(

Comment: @AliForoughi Don't apologize, it is a good question anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Session_End event doesn't fire when the browser is closed, it fires when the server hasn't gotten a request from the user in a specific time persion (by default 20 minutes). That means that if you use Session_End to remove users they wont be able to login for 20 minutes after they have closed the browser.

Two alternative strategies come to mind

1. You can use the onunload event in the browser to send a logout request to the server when the user leaves the page (This of course only works if the user still has net connectivity). The onunload event is also triggered when you reload the page, so you would have to keep track of why the event is triggered to use it.
2. You keep the time of the last request in the user object. That way you can determine how active the user is, and how likely it is that they have left the site. For example find any user that has not done anything for two minutes and log them out.

**EDIT:** As a final point raised in the comments. Instead of viewing your requirement as '*you can only have one login so if your logged in already then don't allow login*' could you change to '*you can only have one login if you have a session open it will be cancelled and a new one created.*'

This way you still keep your one login session per account rule whilst providing a much more robust method of enforcing it.

Comment: i think the first one is not good enough , but the second one to good and i will work on it , thanks man :)

Comment: The methods can be combined to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: I read you edit, but it is out of my privilege to do that , my project manager deside to do that, and i have to. i think (as you said) store the last activity

Comment: thanks benni. you answer is accepted, you are great , thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2):

First off don't use the database as a messaging system. That is a recipe for disaster.

What you should be doing is having a dictionary that holds the logged in user id's and their last action time in the Application storage. Also add script on all pages that pings the server every 2-5 minutes.

Once a ping is received, update the user id's latest activity time, and delete any user id's which have 'timed-out'.

Comment: disaster? WOW , you idea seem good , I will work on it dude , thanks :)

Comment: The reason why it's a bad idea to use the database for messaging in general is that it is very inefficient. In this case you could use the application storage which is way faster. Also in other situations you need to implement complex systems on top of the database to make the communication work properly (e.g. periodic checks instead of relying on events, periodic clean-ups, checks to see if the message was read, queuing etc.). All these mechanisms are usually implemented in proper inter-process communication frameworks.

Comment: "periodic checks instead of relying on events"?!! yes i got you, it is not bad idea, thanks linkerro. i think you mean to store session info in an application state in stead of DB , and store their last activity ?!!

Comment: you help me linkerro , if i can i will accept you answer too. thank you man , you are great and you are very good in english :D shame on me , hahaha , thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have, aside from how/where you store state, is that a user may not log out thus leaving a session alive.    I suggest the following:

1) Change state (delete record in your case) when the user logs out or when the session ends (the session ends after n minutes of inactivity, see your web.config and global.asax for the event handler)

2) If a user tries to log in a second time offer the option to log out the previous session.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try smth. like this:

table structure:

```
 ID
 UserID
 Flag
```

When user is logged in you update your table and set flag to **true** or **1**
and when he is logged out set it to **false** or **0**

When user closed his browser you should decide if you log him out or not. if yes - you catch this event as **Session_End** and log him out by yourself and update the table to
**false** or **0**